# How can i increase (update) a cell in a SQL Table? in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, sql-update

I have a question, currently i have a table named "OrdersAndSerials".
In one of their columns is named Delivery, then i need to take a value of this Column, and and add a value.

Example.
In the green box of this row, the valor of Delivery is 123, but i need to add '10' of this cell.
The final result must be 133.

SQL Table

[image]

Comment: assuming the Delivery column is a INT data type, this should work:
`update table OrdersAndSerials
set delivery = 133
where tskserialbox = 140933vv`
or you can also do this, if you want to specifically SUM it:
`update table OrdersAndSerials
set delivery = delivery + 10
where tskserialbox = 140933vv`

Answer (score 2):

you can easily perform this operation using `UPDATE` statement.

Assuming you need to add `10` to original delivery value, and HUSerialBox is the primary key in this table.

```
update OrdersAndSerials set delivery = delivery + 10 where HUSerialBox = '140933vv';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Delivery column is of the datatype int you can use the `UPDATE` statement to change the value of the cell.

```
UPDATE OrdersAndSerials
SET Delivery = Delivery + 10 /* or whatever value you want to change it by */
WHERE HUSerialBox = '140933vv';
```